# Performance Data Handler hangs for \PhysicalDisk

Tags: c++, winapi

I have been using `PDH` (`Performance Data Handler`) to collect perfmon data about the machine my process is running on. I have had no trouble with `PDH` objects `Processor Information` and `Memory` but when I try to use `PhysicalDisk` my program hangs.

I reduced the code to this test case.

```
void
third()
{
    char path[ PDH_MAX_COUNTER_PATH ];
    DWORD size = 0;
    PDH_STATUS  status;

    strcpy( path, "\\PhysicalDisk(1 E:)\\% Disk Time" );
    // hangs
    status = PdhExpandWildCardPath( NULL, path, 0, & size, PDH_NOEXPANDCOUNTERS );

    HANDLE query;
    PDH_HCOUNTER hCounter;
    status = PdhOpenQuery( NULL, 0, & query );
    // hangs
    status = PdhAddCounter( query, path, 0, & hCounter );
}
```

When I run this code by itself, it works fine.  When I run it in my larger program it hangs but only for `PhysicalDisk`.  My larger program monitors a dozen `PDH` counters with no problems but when I add any `PhysicalDisk` counter, then it hangs.  The counters are defined in an array, so the code is the same for all counters.

When it hangs, this is the stack back trace

```
    ntdll.dll!_ZwDelayExecution@8()  + 0x15 bytes   
    ntdll.dll!_ZwDelayExecution@8()  + 0x15 bytes   
    KernelBase.dll!_Sleep@4()  + 0xf bytes  
    perfdisk.dll!_OpenDiskObject@4()  + 0x105 bytes 
    advapi32.dll!_OpenExtObjectLibrary@4()  + 0x1f9 bytes   
    advapi32.dll!_QueryExtensibleData@4()  - 0x250f bytes   
    advapi32.dll!_PerfRegQueryValue@28()  + 0x26d bytes 
    kernel32.dll!_LocalBaseRegQueryValue@24()  + 0x2754e bytes  
    kernel32.dll!_RegQueryValueExW@24()  + 0xae bytes   
    pdh.dll!_GetSystemPerfData@16()  + 0x92 bytes   
    pdh.dll!_GetObjectId@12()  + 0xdb bytes 
    pdh.dll!_PdhiExpandWildcardPath@24()  + 0x38b bytes 
    pdh.dll!_PdhExpandWildCardPathHA@20()  + 0xcb bytes 
    pdh.dll!_PdhExpandWildCardPathA@20()  + 0x10a bytes 
>   dbb30.dll!third()  Line 2472 + 0x16 bytes   C++
    dbb30.dll!dbbProfileReport::dbbProfileReport()  Line 2490   C++
    dbb30.dll!`dynamic initializer for 'dbbProfileReportObject''()  Line 2367 + 0xd bytes   C++
    msvcr90d.dll!_initterm(void (void)* * pfbegin=0x0121d380, void (void)* * pfend=0x0121fddc)  Line 903    C
    dbb30.dll!_CRT_INIT(void * hDllHandle=0x00ae0000, unsigned long dwReason=1, void * lpreserved=0x0018fd24)  Line 318 + 0xf bytes C
    dbb30.dll!__DllMainCRTStartup(void * hDllHandle=0x00ae0000, unsigned long dwReason=1, void * lpreserved=0x0018fd24)  Line 540 + 0x11 bytes  C
    dbb30.dll!_DllMainCRTStartup(void * hDllHandle=0x00ae0000, unsigned long dwReason=1, void * lpreserved=0x0018fd24)  Line 510 + 0x11 bytes   C
    ntdll.dll!_LdrpCallInitRoutine@16()  + 0x14 bytes   
    ntdll.dll!_LdrpRunInitializeRoutines@4()  - 0x352 bytes 
    ntdll.dll!_LdrpInitializeProcess@8()  - 0x765 bytes 
    ntdll.dll!__LdrpInitialize@8()  + 0xb4f9 bytes  
    ntdll.dll!_LdrInitializeThunk@8()  + 0x10 bytes
```

The `PDH` code starts 6 threads in my process, one of them is in a `function _PerfdiskPnpNotification` which seems to be related.  When I look at assembly code, the main thread is sleeping waiting for this second thread to set a flag.

I have tried running with Admin permissions, but no change. Googling for _`PerfdiskPnpNotification` finds it sometimes tries to open a pop up window. I tried running the larger code from a GUI app, but it hangs too.  I tried the larger code on two machines (both Windows 7) but no luck.  The larger program calls the `PDH` code from a constructor for a global object, I tried the small test case from a ctor on a global, but it worked.
I tried `lodctr /r` to rebuild the registry, but no joy.

Compiling with MSVC 2005 and MSVC 2008 Express.

Comment: First thing to try is to remove initialization from DllMain; only bad things can happen there.

Comment: @Luke No more hang.  Thanks!